# Cannot uninstall or repair Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I've been having some weird issues with Visual Studio 2022 lately so I wanted to run a repair through the Visual Studio Installer.  However, when I run the installer it is giving me errors. I will put a screen shot in to show:[image]

I tried downloading the installer again and it just keeps giving me the same message.  I tried doing a change/uninstall from Control Panel but that just starts the install which gives me this error.
Can anyone please help?  I am not able to do any development and I don't want to format my whole laptop to start over.

Thanks

I did try the suggestions below and downloaded the exe from my visual studio subscription account but now I get this error when running it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, I'd suggest a hard delete of the application. Only try this if Visual Studio is unusable, and therefore you have nothing to lose.

Basically, you can delete the entire folder here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022
```

Then try to reinstall from the installer. This has worked for me in the past, when faced with a similar situation.

There could be registry keys left set that mean this does not solve your problem, but it's the first thing I would try in your current situation.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue a month ago, I deleted the program file, restarted the computer, reinstalled the installer.exe and it ran perfectly. :-)